# (Flutter) How to undo an arithmetic operation in a calculator

Tags: dart, flutter

I am building a Calculator app using flutter. I want to know how can I undo an operation.

For example: If an operation is passed of 'Value+2', and I want to undo this operation. This can be any operation i.e. -,+,*,/,% etc..

Comment: Look up the command pattern

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer 
How exactly can i do that?

Comment: "look up" means Google "command pattern" undo is not as siple as knowing a function name.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer
I found this package that claims that it can do undo command etc. I am very new to coding. can you tell me if this will work? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/command

Comment: Looks good. . .

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a problem related to Flutter, you just need to keep a history of the previous operation like a stack and go to the previous one when the user wants to undo what he has done. You can halso keep trace of every operator and number used to show them again

Comment: Which function do I use for this?

Comment: How to implement this?